# I am getting a garbage value for variable a. I have to input 2 values and print their sum using 2 classes- base and derived

Tags: c++, oop, inheritance

This is a program for single inheritance in C++. I have to derive a class using the protected keyword.
In the first class A, I have declared 2 functions to input and store the value of an integer variable a.
After I have created a derived class, I want to print the values I have inputted for variables a and b and then display their sum on the screen. I got the value of b correctly, but I am getting a garbage value for a. Can someone please help me out and tell me where I went wrong?

```
#include<iostream>
#include<conio.h>
using namespace std;

class A
{
 protected:
       int a;
 public:
    void input_val_a(int);
    int ret_a();
    
};

class B:protected A
{
 int b,c;
 public:
    void input_val_b(int);
    void get_a();         
    void sum();
    void display_value();

};

void A::input_val_a(int y)
{
 a=y;
}

int A::ret_a()
{
 return a;
}


void B::input_val_b(int x)
{
 b=x;
}

void B::sum()
{
 c=ret_a()+b;
}

void B::get_a()
{
 int a=ret_a();
}

void B::display_value()
{
 cout<<"Value of a="<<ret_a()<<endl;
 cout<<"Value of b="<<b<<endl;
 cout<<"Value of c="<<c<<endl;
}

int main()
{
 int a,b;
 B obj;
 A obj1;
 cout<<"Enter the value of a"<<endl;
 cin>>a;
 cout<<"Enter the value of b"<<endl;
 cin>>b;
 obj.input_val_b(b);
 obj1.input_val_a(a);
 obj.get_a();
 obj.sum();
 obj.display_value();

 getch();
 return 0;
}
```

Comment: `int a=ret_a();` in `void B::get_a()` is only changing a local variable. Should it be `a=ret_a();` to change the member `a`?

Comment: In addition you are doing all the operations on `obj`, except for `input_val_a`, which you call on `obj1`. So `obj1.a` is set to something, but `obj.a` remains uninitialize. Regarding my first comment: `get_a` doesn't make any sense, it basically does `a = a`. I'm not really sure what you intended to with all of the classes and functions, better take some time to review what you should do and what functions are really needed.

Answer (score 0):

When you create two instances of objects, unless they share the same memory location, they both are two separate objects. Which means that once you do,

```cpp
B obj;
A obj1;
```

These two are completely separate object. That means that if you assign the value of `a` to `obj1`, the variable `a` in `obj` will not change. And since your not initializing your variables, you will most certainly end up with junk.

**How can I fix this?** 
Its simple, either you have to set the values of `a` and `b` to both `obj` and `obj1`, or else remove one of them, presumably `obj1` (because you only call it once after creating).

Another valid option is to mark `a` as a static variable. This means that `B::a` and `A::a` points to the same variable. Updating it from one object, updates the value of `a` for all the other objects.